# Unnecessary updates in @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

I have model object as follows

```
Employee.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "emp_seq", sequenceName = "seq_employee")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "emp_seq")
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Integer employeeId;
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_NAME")
    private String employeeName;
}

Department.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer departmentId;
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_NAME")
    private String departmentName;
    @Column(name = "LOCATION")
    private String location;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

while saving this it is generating two extra update statements.

Test class

```
    Employee e1 = new Employee();
    e1.setEmployeeName("Employee-1");

    Employee e2 = new Employee();
    e2.setEmployeeName("Employee-2");

    Department d = new Department();
    d.setDepartmentName("Test");
    d.setLocation("Test");

    d.getEmployees().add(e1);
    d.getEmployees().add(e2);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(d);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

on committing the following statements are generated...

```
Hibernate: insert into DEPARTMENT (DEPARTMENT_NAME, LOCATION, DEPARTMENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID) values (?, ?)
**Hibernate: update EMPLOYEE set DEPARTMENT_ID=? where EMPLOYEE_ID=?
**Hibernate: update EMPLOYEE set DEPARTMENT_ID=? where EMPLOYEE_ID=?
```

my question here is why 2 extra update(marked by *) statements are needed?

Answer (score 1):

That's the order on which Hibernate does the operations normally. Take a look at this

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/internal/AbstractFlushingEventListener.html#performExecutions%28org.hibernate.event.spi.EventSource%29

According to this documentation:

> Execute all SQL (and second-level cache updates) **in a special order so
>   that foreign-key constraints cannot be violated**:

Comment: yes, its correct but why cant it insert foreign key directly in the insert statement? why an extra update is needed? that is my question.

Comment: and one more thing is how to avoid those statements?

Comment: I just found out that it do not generate update if the relationship is bidirectional.

Answer (score 0):

When you add Employees to a Department, employees must have a Department ID so that's the reason why Hibernate do an extra update.

If you want to avoid it you can create first the department, and then the employees adding manually Department id

Answer (score 0):

Due to the @OneToMany @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID") that annotates the attribute Department.employees the table 
EMPLOYEE has a foreign key to the table DEPARTMENT. When you persiste the new department with the two employees a new row is inserted into the table DEPARTMENT and two rows are inserted into the table EMPLOYEE but the column DEPARTMENT_ID is null. Then two updates are executed to set this column and relate the EMPLOYEE rows with the DEPARTMENT row.

The question is why this is not done in one step, i.e. instead of executing the following:

```
Hibernate: insert into DEPARTMENT (DEPARTMENT_NAME, LOCATION, DEPARTMENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID) values (?, ?)
**Hibernate: update EMPLOYEE set DEPARTMENT_ID=? where EMPLOYEE_ID=?
**Hibernate: update EMPLOYEE set DEPARTMENT_ID=? where EMPLOYEE_ID=?
```

the following should be executed:

```
Hibernate: insert into DEPARTMENT (DEPARTMENT_NAME, LOCATION, DEPARTMENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
```